# Is the data/AI stored inside or JARVIS and then Vision completely erased?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

When Thanos cracks the Stone out of Vision in *Avengers: Infinity War*, Vision loses his color and consciousness. I’m not sure if he was snapped out of existence. But what is for sure is that he is longer active.

Did Tony Stark download a copy of the data of JARVIS/Vision in a hard-drive? Or is the data stored in the system gone forever?

Comment: most likely his knowledge and personality weren't stored in the stone, so it could probably still be retrieved. I doubt that he'll make another appearance though simply because Marvel doesn't want/need him to, and/or the actor doesn't want to come back.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe-Levi Disney+ streaming service is apparently planning a show about Wanda and Vision, so this might be premature.  Although the series may well be about the 2 years they spent together during the gap between Civil War and Infinity War...

Answer (score 1):

Did Tony Stark download a copy of the data of JARVIS/Vision in a hard-drive? Or is the data stored in the system gone forever?

## We presume the "data" is destroyed

...since there is no evidence of Tony (or anyone else) mentioning it.

Certainly the Vision is primarily cybernetic but it's doubtful if the data was stored in something as simple as hard drive.

### Could it be reconstructed?

Possibly, in *Infinity War*, Banner emphasises that the Vision is more than the Stone

> Bruce Banner: Because you might have a choice. Your mind is made up of a complex construct of overlays. J.A.R.V.I.S., Ultron, Tony, me, the Stone. All of them mixed together. All of them learning from one another.
>
> Wanda Maximoff: You're saying Vision isn't just the stone?
>
> Bruce Banner: I'm saying that if we take out the stone, there's still a whole lot of Vision left. Perhaps the best parts.

Other than the stone, the other constituent parts are still "available" (or capable of being reconstructed) in order to make a new Vision.

It wouldn't be the same though since a fundamental part is now missing.

Comment: IMO, stone acts as a bridge between every other aspect Banner mentioned. and losing it might've caused a barrier in data flow which makes him un-alive(if we can use that word for Vision)